# Cordova is not defined after onDeviceReady

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, visual-studio-cordova, ripple

I am trying to build a Cordova app and test it in Ripple. When I start the application the onDeviceReady hook fires and I have `cordova` variable and all my plugin variables are accessible.

However after the application loads and I try to access `cordova` from console, e.g., it is undefined.

I am not sure what is going on, but somehow it disappears. Is it supposed to work at all like that with Ripple or I have to test everything only on real device / emulator?

P.S. It happens in a completely new blank project created in VS2015 as well. So I don't really understand how I am supposed to access `cordova` and plugins if it becomes undefined somehow?

Comment: @llya Add some code snippet please...

Comment: @Gandhi There is no code snippet really, after the app loads I just try to access cordova in console and it is not available... It won't be available the same way for my own js code outside of onready...

Comment: is your device ready event getting fired? Cordova plugins are accessible only with in device ready callback listeners

Comment: Yes, device ready works fine. But how will I work with plugins if it's only during device ready? Or they are available always on a real device/emulator?

Comment: its not only during device ready but after device ready event is fired... I suggest you to look at this link for a sample rather than explaining - https://github.com/gandhirajan/Cordova_QR_Scanner/blob/master/www/js/app.js

Comment: Well, it's more complicated than I thought. What I really try to do is to get access to cordova in a site with external url, rather than all bundled within an app. Does not seem to be easy unfortunately. Thanks for help though :)

Comment: Have posted the answer for the benefit of others. Please accept if helpful.

Comment: i m not 100% sure but you will get cordova as undefined on ripple cos cordova.js is available once you build an app..ripple is not an emulator..its just web only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the answer. The trick is to stay within the realm of the application on the device and load all of the javascript from the remote server. In a SPA application like Angular case, it's only the bootstrap `index.html` of the application that is required and nothing else. All the `.js` files can be referenced and the application will "auto-update" itself.

Comment: to run an external `url mydomain.com` e.g. that can access device capabilites

Comment: you can use inappbrowser for the same I guess and still use device capabilities

Comment: Well, it apparently did not work at all, `window.nagiator.store` exists when I access it from console, but not from the app. I don't really understand it :( And `window.navigator` from console and app are two different objects...

Comment: Apparently what I try to achieve seems to be not officially supporte: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/next/#loading-remote-content. So I guess I'll have to rethink the whole approach :)

Comment: did you read the whole link. It did mention about inapp browser as I suggested

Comment: @Gandhi Yes, I read that. But it won't give me the access to plugins...

Comment: what plugin you need to access and what exactly is your requirement after opening URL?

Comment: I'd like to process a subscription, i.e. buy a subscription for the app and there is a plugin for that available that injects `store` global variables, that is not available to the website running on the URL. But since it's not supported I guess I have to give up on the idea :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for help @Gandhi, I have actually found a solution that works. I have the "index.html" that references the remote script files, and my whole angular application is actually inside this js files. It was an obvious solution I did not think about for some reason :(

Comment: Glad you cracked it. again that boils down to have the complete functionality within device ready event listener :)

Answer (score 1):

Cordova plugin code can be accessed only after device ready event is fired which ensures that Cordova and the plugins are loaded successfully.

Have look at this [sample code](https://github.com/gandhirajan/Cordova_QR_Scanner/blob/master/www/js/app.) for better understanding. Hope it helps.

Update: If you wanna access external URL through the app then you gotta use InAppBrowser to achieve it.

Answer (score 1):

Cordova.js referenced in your index.html is available once you build an app using Cordova. While testing in the browser, the file isn't available. Since you are testing on ripple emulator, which is not a mobile emulator, you will get cordova as undefined only.

Run the Cordova app on a emulator/device, then you will get the Cordova variable.

Comment: browser platform too has Cordova.js file available after build platform. Infact some plugins are supported in browser platform too. So I dont think its an appropriate answer

Comment: please knock off this answer.it may misguide other users who are looking for a right solution